# Referencing and dereferencing a db connection in rust

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rocket

My question is about **dereferencing** and **referencing** in rust.

I have the following code:

```
#[database("pg_db")]
struct PgDbConn(diesel::PgConnection);

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .attach(PgDbConn::fairing())
        .mount("/", routes![find_one, find_all])
        .launch();
}

#[get("/<id>", format = "json")]
fn find_one(conn: PgDbConn, id: i32) -> Result<Json<Person>, NotFound<String>> {
    let one: QueryResult<Person> = person.find(id).first(&*conn); // Notice here deref & ref
    ...
```

I would like to know how my `PgDbConn` struct ends up as a connection. Can someone please explain the mechanism in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at (part of) [the implementation of the `database` attribute macro](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.4/contrib/codegen/src/database.rs#L127-L141):

```rust
Ok(quote! {
    //...
    impl ::std::ops::Deref for #guard_type {
        type Target = #conn_type;

        #[inline(always)]
        fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
            &self.0
        }
    }

    impl ::std::ops::DerefMut for #guard_type {
        #[inline(always)]
        fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
            &mut self.0
        }
    }
})
```

`#guard_type` is `PgDbConn` and `#conn_type` is `diesel::PgConnection` in your example, so the produced code looks like this:

```rust
impl ::std::ops::Deref for PgDbConn {
    type Target = diesel::PgConnection;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl ::std::ops::DerefMut for PgDbConn {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}
```

With `Deref` and `DerefMut`, you can implement dereference for your own types, in this case `PgDbConn`. Now, you can write `*conn` to get a `diesel::PgConnection` from your `PgDbConn`. However, you want a *reference* to `diesel::PgConnection`. To get a reference, you have to again reference the dereferenced `PgDbConn`, so the end result is `&*conn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed and relevant answer!

Comment: A even better solution on rockets side would be to implement `diesel::Connection` directly on `#guard_type`, so that the user don't have to do the `&*conn` deref conversion. This seems to be a quite common source of confusion. It would likely make sense to fill an issue in their bug tracker for that.